# What happens when you dont need black essence anymore?

Tags: hades

I really wonder... I only need a few more 1000 black essence upgrades, and then, well, I don't think I'll have anything to spend essence on.

Most ressources you can trade, but essence is rarely tradable.

So I'm curious and want to get spoiled. Whats gonna happen when I will have bought all upgrades? Will I just stack essence to infinity and beyond?

Comment: Just curious, did you get all the red and green upgrades from the mirror?  (It took me way too long to realize there were green ones)

Comment: They are all maxed except the last ones (the one where you can modify the next room or the boons.) They are 1k a piece. Seeing as you need 340k essence to complete, and I think I'm somewhere like 30k in right now, I guess they got LOTS of levels.

Comment: Oh I just checked the Resource Director list... thats where they want you to spend all that Black essence lol. But I wonder after all that what can you do with the now useless black essence.

Comment: If you just need the last red and green one, it should be 21,000.  https://hades.gamepedia.com/Mirror_of_Night This seems to have a decent chart that also tells you the total required to max each upgrade.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have really run out of the need for Darkness, then I must commend you as you've gathered at least the 340,000 required for the [Resource Director](https://hades.gamepedia.com/Resource_Director).

There is also at least one quest (having to do with Nyx, obviously) that needs a few thousand darkness to complete at the house contractor.

Also, as @JMac mentioned in the comments, don't forget that there are 2 sets of mirror upgrades.

Comment: So yeah I'm A LOT further from that than I tought. But what happens when you are done with the ressouce director? (I'm gonna guess you are just... done with the game lol)

Comment: After gathering that much darkness, you become one with the game lol.

Comment: Yeah I would guess at that point you are a speedrunner or just straight up married the game. Would be what, about 1000 escape attempts? Pretty sure at that point any other currency is also useless.